# How can I output the date with ConsoleLogger?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a console command and I'm initializing ConsoleLogger in the `initialize` method:

`$this->logger = new ConsoleLogger($output);`

But the date is not outputted in the console. Is it possible to prefix the output with the datetime?

Comment: Excuse me but I don't use symfony hence why this is a comment and not an answer; Looking at the [API;](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Console/Logger/ConsoleLogger.html) what you have done so far is declare the `OutputInterface`. it appears you have to do `$this->logger->log($level,"text")` to actually output a message. (where $level is the level of the message in the log)

Comment: Please show an example of how the output looks, how it should look instead and (the relevant parts of) your command class.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old topic, but it's the first result when you google for "symfony console log date", that's why I'd like to share what I found when trying to solve this.

According to the Symfony docs, you can specify a custom formatter (found in old Symfony 2.6 docs)
https://symfony.com/doc/2.6//cookbook/logging/monolog_console.html

```yaml
    # app/config/services.yml
    services:
        my_formatter:
            class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Formatter\ConsoleFormatter
            arguments:
                # NOTE
                # The placeholder to use in the `format` is enclosed in single `%` (ex.: `%datetime%`)
                # However, here we escape `%` characters so Symfony will not interpret them as service parameters.
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-parameters
                - "[%%datetime%%] %%start_tag%%%%message%%%%end_tag%% (%%level_name%%) %%context%% %%extra%%\n"
```

But that's not doing the trick already.
Taking a look at the source of ConsoleFormatter, I found this:

```php
    const SIMPLE_FORMAT = "%datetime% %start_tag%%level_name%%end_tag% <comment>[%channel%]</> %message%%context%%extra%\n";
    const SIMPLE_DATE = 'H:i:s';
```

So there date is set as H:i:s here.
Luckily this date can be overwritten with the `date_format` option.

---

This is how I solved it now:

In my monolog.yaml I added the formatter

```yaml
        console:
            type:   console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console"]
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_NORMAL: DEBUG
            formatter: console_log_formatter
```

And in services.yml I added the custom formatter with my date_format set

```yaml
        console_log_formatter:
            class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Formatter\ConsoleFormatter
            arguments:
                - date_format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to define the verbosity level

```
$this->consoleLogger = new ConsoleLogger($output, [LogLevel::INFO => OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_NORMAL]);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: This is not correct as the verbosity level doesn't affects the output of a particular part of the log, but it decides if the entire log line has to be outputted or not. The correct answer is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62891890/1399706